# Please review - question put on hold

Tags: discussion

In agreement with the "Help Center > Asking" section, I would like to ask for a review of the question I posted on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58284/how-to-better-manage-translate-a-multilanguage-blog). I consider this question clear and absolutely non-opinion based. As stated in the question I would like to receive answers based on facts or official Google best practices, and the answers must be explained why.

I kindly ask the moderators to review this question and consider it for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

I can clearly see that you have taken the time to write that question and the fact that its been closed for one reason or another can be frustrating, but it has happened to us all (even mods). Now I don't speak on behalf of the other mods but I have reviewed your question and I believe the question is not fit for Pro Webmasters so to speak, however this question is perfect for our Chat Channel.

Please note that when moderators close any questions they are unable to attach several reasons, this is because of the way the closure system works, it's got far better in recent times and I'm sure we will see many more updates to help our users.

Now jumping back to your question, I have reviewed your question I see:

1. A question that to specific on your site and the way the question is formatted unlikely to help others `This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help anybody else. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting.`
2. A question that promotes too many different possible answers, granted that your asking for best practice but there is many rights to your question which is not a good fit. `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.`
3. You have many solutions listed that many are correct, picking one could been seen as opinionated, granted you want the best practice but simply adding best practice to the question doesn't exempt the question from the rules of the site. `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

My advice would be to narrow down your question, maybe using our chat channel and then completely simplifying the question and made more generic.